# Angular2 - OnInit is not defined

Tags: typescript, angular

I'm trying to implement the angular 2 onInit function but I get the following error in the console:

> Error: ReferenceError: OnInit is not defined(...)

Can somebody point out what I'm doing wrong?

This is my component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from 'angular2/core';
import { ViewEncapsulation } from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'Landing',
    templateUrl: '/app/views/landing.html',
    styleUrls: ['../app/styles/landing.css'],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})

export class LandingComponent implements OnInit {

    function checkOverflow() {
        var element = document.querySelector('.appContainer');
        if( (element.offsetHeight < element.scrollHeight) || (element.offsetWidth < element.scrollWidth)){
           // your element have overflow
          console.log('OVERFLOW!');
        }
        else{
          console.log('NO OVERFLOW');
        }
    }

    OnInit() {
        checkOverflow();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use `single` import instead of two import statements. Also use `@` before `@angular/core` if you are using `rc`(release candidate) version

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
```

You should implement `ngOnInit` method as you component class `implements OnInit` class

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.checkOverflow();
}
```

Additionally don't use `function` in the way you are currently using in typescript file, do convert it to `checkOverflow(){ ... }` format & then call it like `this.checkOverflow()`